# BeautifulSoup - How to Loop Through a "tr" Tag?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to loop through this BeerAdvocate page (https://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/styles/35/) in order to scrape the beer name, abv, rating and so on. However, I'm not sure how to build a loop to go over the whole page.

For example, I'm doing as follows regarding the beer name:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/styles/35/"
results = requests.get(url) 

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
beer_name = []

beer_div = soup.find_all('div',id='ba-content')

for container in beer_div:

#beer name
name = container.find_all('a')[12].text
beer_name.append(name)

print(beer_name)
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Pls check whether my answer satisfies ur requirement

Answer (score 4):

First identify the `table`, then find all the `tr` tags within the `table`, then loop through the `tr` tags to print the text.

```
beer_table = soup.find('table')

tr_tags = beer_table.find_all('tr')[3:]

for tr in tr_tags:
    beer_name.append(tr.td.text)

beer_name = beer_name[:-1]

print(beer_name)
```

Output:

```
['Ayinger Celebrator', 'Troegenator', 'Spaten Optimator', 'Salvator', 'Korbinian', 'Samichlaus Classic Bier', 'Samuel Adams Double Bock (Imperial Series)', 'Consecrator', 'Andechser Doppelbock Dunkel', 'Birra Moretti La Rossa', 'Perkulator Coffee Dopplebock', 'EKU 28', 'Liberator Doppelbock', 'Augustiner Bräu Maximator', "Smuttynose S'muttonator (Heritage Series)", 'Butthead Doppelbock', 'Autumnal Fire', 'Weltenburger Kloster Asam-Bock', 'Wasatch The Devastator Double Bock', 'St. Victorious', 'Urbock 23°', 'Voodoovator', 'Saxonator Dunkles Doppelbock', 'Doppel-Hirsch', 'Josephs Brau Winter Brew', 'Duck-Rabbator', 'Troegenator - Bourbon Barrel-Aged', 'Ettaler Curator Dunkler Doppelbock (US Import Version)', 'Blonde Doppelbock', 'Snow Blind Doppelbock', 'Doppelbock Dunkel', 'Tucher Bajuvator Doppelbock', 'Dark Heathen Triple Bock', 'Winter Bock', 'Deep Water Dopplebock', 'Doppelbock Grande Cuvée Printemps', 'Lobotomy Bock', 'Sled Dog Dopplebock', 'Primátor Double Bock Beer', 'Icelandic Doppelbock', 'Dopple Bock', "St. Nikolaus Bock Bier - Brewer's Reserve", 'Double Skull', 'Emancipator Doppelbock', 'Winter-Bock', 'Granitbock', "Henry's Farm Double Bock", 'Double Vision Doppelbock', 'Massacre', "Fireman's Brew Brunette Beer"]
```

Here is the full code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/styles/35/"
results = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(results.content, 'html.parser')
beer_name = []

beer_table = soup.find('table')

tr_tags = beer_table.find_all('tr')[3:]

for tr in tr_tags:
    beer_name.append(tr.td.text)

beer_name = beer_name[:-1]

print(beer_name)
```

Hope that this helps!

Comment: Sushil, would you please share the whole code? It's not bringing the full list to me.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but when I run this code, the results are always: "[  ]".

Comment: Is it so? It works absolutely fine for me. Maybe try changing the parser to ```html5lib``` or ```lxml```.

Answer (score 1):

To correctly parse the HTML, use `lxml` or `html5lib` parser:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/styles/35/'
soup = BeautifulSoup( requests.get(url).content, 'lxml' )

print('{:<60} {:<70} {:<10} {:<10}'.format('Name', 'Brewery', 'ABV', 'Ratings', 'Avg'))
print('-' * 150)
 
for row in soup.select('tr:has(.hr_bottom_light)'):
    tds = [td.text for td in row.select('td')]
    print('{:<60} {:<70} {:<10} {:<10}'.format(*tds))
```

Prints:

```
Name                                                         Brewery                                                                ABV        Ratings   
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ayinger Celebrator                                           Ayinger Privatbrauerei                                                 6.70       6,843     
Troegenator                                                  Tröegs Brewing Company                                                 8.20       3,437     
Spaten Optimator                                             Spaten-Franziskaner-Bräu                                               7.60       3,218     
Salvator                                                     Paulaner Brauerei                                                      7.90       2,948     
Korbinian                                                    Bayerische Staatsbrauerei Weihenstephan                                7.40       2,883     
Samichlaus Classic Bier                                      Brauerei Schloss Eggenberg                                             14.00      2,182     
Samuel Adams Double Bock (Imperial Series)                   Boston Beer Company (Samuel Adams)                                     9.50       1,947     
Consecrator                                                  Bell's Brewery - Eccentric Café & General Store                        8.00       1,534     
Andechser Doppelbock Dunkel                                  Klosterbrauerei Andechs                                                7.10       1,259     
Birra Moretti La Rossa                                       Birra Moretti (Heineken)                                               7.20       1,077     
Perkulator Coffee Dopplebock                                 Dark Horse Brewing Company                                             7.00       1,028     
EKU 28                                                       Kulmbacher Brauerei AG                                                 11.00      742       
Liberator Doppelbock                                         Thomas Hooker Brewing Company                                          8.50       701       
Augustiner Bräu Maximator                                    Augustiner-Bräu                                                        7.50       698       
Smuttynose S'muttonator (Heritage Series)                    Smuttynose Brewing Company                                             8.20       653       
Butthead Doppelbock                                          Tommyknocker Brewery                                                   8.20       606       
Autumnal Fire                                                Capital Brewery                                                        7.80       604       
Weltenburger Kloster Asam-Bock                               Klosterbrauerei Weltenburg                                             6.90       591       
Wasatch The Devastator Double Bock                           Utah Brewers Cooperative                                               8.00       588       
St. Victorious                                               Victory Brewing Company - Downingtown                                  7.60       578       
Urbock 23°                                                   Brauerei Schloss Eggenberg                                             9.60       460       
Voodoovator                                                  Atwater Brewery                                                        9.50       420       
Saxonator Dunkles Doppelbock                                 Jack's Abby Brewing                                                    8.50       379       
Doppel-Hirsch                                                Der HirschBrau/Privatbrauerei Höss                                     7.20       379       
Josephs Brau Winter Brew                                     Trader Joe's Brewing Company                                           7.50       345       
Duck-Rabbator                                                The Duck-Rabbit Craft Brewery                                          8.50       344       
Troegenator - Bourbon Barrel-Aged                            Tröegs Brewing Company                                                 11.50      330       
Ettaler Curator Dunkler Doppelbock (US Import Version)       Klosterbrauerei Ettal / Ettaler Klosterbetriebe GmbH                   9.00       314       
Blonde Doppelbock                                            Capital Brewery                                                        7.80       295       
Snow Blind Doppelbock                                        Starr Hill Brewery                                                     7.70       278       
Doppelbock Dunkel                                            Brauerei Schloss Eggenberg                                             8.50       264       
Tucher Bajuvator Doppelbock                                  Brauerei Tucher Brau                                                   7.20       264       
Dark Heathen Triple Bock                                     Kuhnhenn Brewing Company                                               12.50      262       
Winter Bock                                                  Gordon Biersch Brewery Restaurant                                      7.50       255       
Deep Water Dopplebock                                        Thomas Creek Brewery                                                   7.00       232       
Doppelbock Grande Cuvée Printemps                            Les Trois Mousquetaires                                                8.60       213       
Lobotomy Bock                                                Indian Wells Brewing Company                                           10.50      208       
Sled Dog Dopplebock                                          Wagner Valley Brewing Co.                                              8.50       201       
Primátor Double Bock Beer                                    Pivovar Náchod a.s.                                                    10.50      189       
Icelandic Doppelbock                                         Einstök Ölgerð (Einstök Beer Company)                                  6.70       187       
Dopple Bock                                                  Sprecher Brewing Company                                               7.85       186       
St. Nikolaus Bock Bier - Brewer's Reserve                    Pennsylvania Brewing Company                                           8.50       185       
Double Skull                                                 Epic Brewing Company                                                   9.00       180       
Emancipator Doppelbock                                       Christian Moerlein Brewing Company                                     7.00       179       
Winter-Bock                                                  Einbecker Brauhaus AG                                                  7.50       169       
Granitbock                                                   Brauerei Hofstetten Krammer GmbH & Co. KG                              7.30       158       
Henry's Farm Double Bock                                     Two Roads Brewing Company                                              7.80       156       
Double Vision Doppelbock                                     Grand Teton Brewing Co.                                                8.00       156       
Massacre                                                     Wolverine State Brewing Company                                        14.50      147       
Fireman's Brew Brunette Beer                                 Fireman's Brew, Inc.                                                   8.00       143
```